# I need to make the timestamp value to repeat for the start of each group

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

Hi I have the following pattern :

```
timestamp                   |   group
: -----------------------   | :-----------------------
2020-11-30 10:00:00+00:00   |   1
2020-11-30 11:00:00+00:00   |   1
2020-11-30 12:00:00+00:00   |   1
2020-11-30 13:00:00+00:00   |   1
2020-11-30 14:00:00+00:00   |   2
2020-11-30 15:00:00+00:00   |   2
2020-11-30 16:00:00+00:00   |   3
2020-11-30 17:00:00+00:00   |   3
2020-11-30 18:00:00+00:00   |   3
2020-11-30 19:00:00+00:00   |   3
```

I need the timestamp to repeat whenever the group changes and then for it remain the same sort of indicating the group change start timestamp as illustrated :

```
timestamp                   |   group
: -----------------------   |   : -----------------------
2020-11-30 10:00:00+00:00   |   1
2020-11-30 10:00:00+00:00   |   1
2020-11-30 10:00:00+00:00   |   1
2020-11-30 10:00:00+00:00   |   1
2020-11-30 14:00:00+00:00   |   2
2020-11-30 14:00:00+00:00   |   2
2020-11-30 16:00:00+00:00   |   3
2020-11-30 16:00:00+00:00   |   3
2020-11-30 16:00:00+00:00   |   3
2020-11-30 16:00:00+00:00   |   3
```

I have the data in  a pandas dataframe.

Comment: Do you need add seconds?

Comment: No, it was a formatting error. Got there by mistake. Have reformatted,

Comment: Then it is dupe, use `df['timestamp'] = df.groupby('group')['timestamp'].transform('first')`